# How to intercept a variable value

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I m trying to create a chrome extension that calculates the average of some numbers shown at a certain webpage.
The webpage uses this function to show them:

```
function MakeBody(Property, dValue, Color){
    document.write ("<tr>")
    document.write ("<td width='16'> &nbsp;</td>");
    document.write ("<td width='10'>&nbsp;</td>");
    document.write ("<td><p class='NormalText'>&nbsp;&nbsp;<font color='"+Color+"'>"+Property+"</font></p></td>");
    document.write ("<td><p class='NormalText'>&nbsp;&nbsp;<font color='"+Color+"'><b>"+dValue+"</font></b></p></td>");
    document.write ("<td width='16'>&nbsp;</td>");
    document.write ("</tr>");
}
```

The values I need to intercept and calculate their average are from the "dValue" variable. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

Only if you can replace the `MakeBody` function with a new function that does the manipulation, and then invokes the original:

```
   // cache the original
var __MakeBody__ = MakeBody;

   // replace it with yours
MakeBody = function(Property, dValue, Color) {
    // manipulate 'dValue' here

        // invoke the original
    return __MakeBody__.call(this, Property, dValue, Color);
};
```